# Evento en Calendario Zimbra desde java

Tags: java

Muchos saludos a todos.

Si alguien puede orientarme.

Estoy desarrollando un módulo y en donde se lanzan alertas por ciertos criterios.
Las alertas son notificadas mediante el envio de correos, sin problemas.

En esta etapa surgela necesidad que mediante esas alertas se pueda crear un Evento en el calendario de Zimbra (Una cita programada), para que se pueda aceptar y quede programada una alarma en la agenda de Zimbra.

El sistema esta desarrollado en java 6

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** y **[¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)**. Debes [edit] y mejorar tu pregunta. Agrega en la pregunta qué has intentado, qué errores tienes, etc.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow en español. Te invito a hacer el [tour] para aprender sobre el funcionamiento del sitio, y a leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). En su forma actual, la pregunta carece de un poco más de detalle. Al menos, información de los mecanismos que el producto que mencionas (Zimbra) ofrece. En su forma actual, no es una pregunta sobre programación, en si.

Comment: ¿Sabes por ejemplo, si ese producto soporta? [iCalendar](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar)

Comment: Voy a verficar lo de iCalendar que mensionas...  os comentare como va

Comment: jachguacate.  Revisando la documentación de zimbra, los eventos del calendario de zimbra se pueden verificar sin inconvenientes en ical de ios o calendar de Android, y se puede importar eventos creados en esas apps.
Lo que da a entender Zimbra si soporta icalendar.